# Are Android type parameters also an objects

Tags: android, object, methods, parameters

How can it be:

```
final Button okButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.okButton);
```

This is very clear that it is a variable declaration + assignment, absolutely not an object !
If so, how can I do the following, and actually operate a methods on it ?:

```
okButton.setOnClickListener(this);
okButton.setOnLongClickListener(this);
```

??

It makes confusion...

Thanks...

Comment: I meant a variable... (fixed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A variable can be an Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

If you look at the [documentation for findViewById](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29) it takes a parameter of type int and returns a View.

You have prefixed `findViewById` with `(Button)` to tell the system that you are expecting that passing R.id.okButton  to findViewById will return a View which is actually an instance of [Button (a sub-class of View)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html).

That instruction `(Button)` [casts](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-object-typecasting) the View returned by `findViewById` to the Type Button and assigns it to your variable `okButton`.

So

- R.id.okButton is an int which is passed as a parameter to
- findViewById which is a method (probably of an Activity I guess)
- which returns an Object of type View which can be cast to an object
- of type Button which is assigned to your Button variable

Comment: So you say that in Java, parameter is actually an object with one attribute ? And the different between an object and parameter is the number of attributes and the keyword 'new' for objects only ?

Comment: No. A parameter is a piece of information passed to a method. It could be a primitive type like an int or an Object. The difference between Object and parameter is that one is an Object and can contain methods and the other is a parameter (there are many differences between them). You really do want to read the basic Java documentation and some basic Object Oriented examples to get the meanings of these basic terms straight

Comment: I know all of that, but what seems to be the different between: 
private Button okButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.okButton); to this: Button okButton = new Button(); okButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.okButton) ??? thx

Comment: In the first example there you get a View from findViewById and cast it to button storing a reference to it in the okButton variable. In the second you make a new button and store a reference to it in the okButton and then you get a View from findViewById and store a reference to it in the okButton variable. That second assignment replaces the reference to the first button.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with Android. You seem to be confused about Java syntax. "`final Button okButton`" is a declaration of an object "`okButton`" of type "`Button`". The object reference has been declared "`final`" so that it cannot be assigned again.

Comment: ... actually it can just with some  very basic reflection code.

Comment: I know but a new object needs to be declare with the keyword 'new' otherwise it is a variable, isn't it ? if not, how can you differ between them both (var vs obj) ?

Comment: So okButton is a variable of type Button. Hence you can call methods of Button class on it. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I have not completely understood it well, because int is also an int type, but I can not operate methods on it...
So again what is the different between this and: Button okButton = new Button(); ??

Comment: I could try to explain this. But you would benefit more by reading a Java book. (I am not trying to offend)

Comment: Yep, if you read through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ then you'll be able to pick up these basic terms and concepts which aren't necessarily specific to Java

Answer (score 0):

`Button okButton` means you have created a Button object name **okButton** then you instantiated it by a button type object which you created in **xml** and gave a unique identity name okButton.

Another way is

```
Button okButton = new Button(this);
```

Actually there is no difference between them accept in second you have create it dynamically and can add/remove them without touching xml.

Comment: so what seems to be the different between: Button okButton = new Button(); ??

Comment: in your comment you explicitly create a Button and assign it to a variable. In the case of findViewById you ask the method for a button. You don't need to know or care if it makes a new Button or gets a reference to one that already exists.